# Highcharts x axis month and year showing twice

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am not sure why month and year is displaying twice in x axis. Please advice

My highcharts code.. is my code wrong in defining x axis?

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $.post('data.php', function (json) {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'area'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Statistics',
            },
            yAxis: {
                type: 'double',
                min: 0
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %y', this.value);
                    },
                    //dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    // month: '%b \'%y',
                    //  year: '%Y'
                    // }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: Stat!,
                data: eval(json)
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: are you on IE8? are the data coming back in the json variable half of the data you have in the graph?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `minTickInterval` (as 30days) - Highcharts probably calculates interval as two weeks between ticks. You are changing formatter, so it displays as you wanted. If you disable formatter, you will see what I mean.